# Does SNS -> SQS -> Lambda (inside VPC) require VPCEndpoint to READ data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I started to wonder whether or not VPC endpoints is required in following case:

I have an SNS topic that serves as an event bus of some sort.
Without dwelling on that topic, lets move further. That SNS is linked to SQS via AWS serverless event source for a lambda. You know, something like:

```
FoobarEvent:
  Type: SNS
  Properties:
    Topic: !Ref Topic
    SqsSubscription: true
```

And that's it. So I am letting `sam` create SQS to queue messages pushed into SNS.
Now, to the point. Lambda itself is configured to stay inside of private subnets.

```
VpcConfig:
  SecurityGroupIds: [...]
  SubnetIds: [...]
```

So naturally, I expect that a VPC interface either or both to SNS and SQS services is required.
But!?:

1. Is that really so?
2. If I won't define endpoints but still have NATs will those be even used?
3. If I will have neither endpoints nor NATs will this still work?

I am asking, because it makes sense that would need either SNS endpoint to push from private lambda to it or SQS endpoint to push to that respectively. I can't, though, get my head around what happens in there in the background? Lambda polls on interval on designated queue. But if its in private subnet, how does it reach that queue? And how SNS or SQS reaches each other?

Comment: So lambda in a private subnet publishes messages into your SNS->SQS-> other lambda?

Comment: Right now I am publishing to SNS from tests from my own laptop. Messages are reaching the SNS and in turn SQS linked to lambda placed in private subnets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that really so?

You don't need to use SNS nor SQS enpoints in your VPC, based on the extra info from comments.

> If I won't define endpoints but still have NATs will those be even used?

NAT is also not needed if your lambda function does not need to call external APIs or access internet.

> If I will have neither endpoints nor NATs will this still work?

Yes, unless your function needs to access internet to access external API or invoke some other AWS services.

Comment: I actually removed all NATs and related endpoints and my tests that were circling aforementioned SNS and SQS passed. That actually brings my to another point.

Does the traffic stays inside of AWS? Like for instance, message goes from SNS to SQS and later lambda polls from SQS. Does that stay inside of VPC and never reaches public network?

Comment: Just wondering, how secure are my messages if there is no explicit private networking involved.

Comment: Regarding "message goes from SNS to SQS and later lambda polls from SQS. Does that stay inside of (my) VPC?" If I understand your question, no, it's never in your VPC. It's all within the AWS control plane. The Lambda control plane ultimately presents the data directly to your Lambda function.

Comment: Sorry, acceptance is in order, true, I just went to sleep :).

Comment: @jarmod but AWS control plane != public internet, correct?

Comment: @kornicameister See [global network](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/global_network/) and [global infrastructure](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regions_az/). All low-latency private network infrastructure.

Comment: @jarmod Hi. The aws white paper explicitly says that sqs -> lambda goes over internet. Thus, I'm not sure what role AWS global infrastructure plays here.

Comment: @Marcin Interesting, can you point me at the phrase you're looking at in the PDF?

Comment: @jarmod `Invoke Data Path` section.

Comment: @jarmodaffic to
the load balancer **passes over the internet**, and is secured with TLS.

Comment: @Marcin That's request/response Lambda invocation traffic from a client, such as awscli, an AWS SDK client or an API client via API Gateway. I don't read that as including internal AWS traffic between SQS and Lambda.

Comment: @jarmod In the next paragraph: "Invocations from Amazon Kinesis and DynamoDB streams,
**SQS queues**, Application Load Balancer, and API Gateway follow the request-response
path."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223451/discussion-between-jarmod-and-marcin).